# How to duplicate a field in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have table like this in a DataFrame

[image]

I was wondering how I can duplicate the 'original id' field all the way down to the bottom?

Thanks.

Comment: you can just do `df['original id'] = df['original id'].iloc[0]` or `df['original id'] = df['original id'].ffill()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):

```
df['original id'] = df['original id'].ffill()
```